# How to set the default controller in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, config, default

I have `UserControler` and I run it in virtual server http://basic.com/index.php?r=user/index. How can I set up `UserController` and action `index` to be the default when I go to http://basic.com

Comment: What have you tried?  And did you google this: http://www.larryullman.com/2013/02/18/understanding-routes-in-the-yii-framework/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Did you try in your config:

```
'defaultRoute' => 'user/index'
```

[Default Controller](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-controllers.md)

Comment: How can i set default in Controller ?, ex, if login will another default router

Answer (score 20):

Like few people already said, you need to add `defaultRoute` in the configurations file.
Here is how it should look:

`//config/web.php` in **basic** template  or `backend/config/main.php` in **advanced**

```
$config = [
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
    ],
    'params' => $params,
    'defaultRoute' => 'user/index',
];
```

Answer (score 13):

This can be set within the config, see [Default Controller](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-controllers.md#default-controller-):

```
[
    'defaultRoute' => 'main',
]
```

But note that this is closely related to routing, which can be completely customized by `urlManager` component. Then if you want let's say `domain/profile` to behave like `domain/user/profile` then these rules for `urlManager` might be another way to go:

```
'rules' => array(
    '<action:\w+>' => 'user/<action>', // <-- use UserController by default
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
),
```

Hopefully this will help someone :)

Answer (score 3):

Open the `web.php` file from your configuration folder, and add the following:

`'defaultRoute' => 'admin'`

to your `$config` array.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Note that `defaultRoute` is ignored, when `strictParsing` is set to enabled in the `urlManager` config. Refer to the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5892

The following config is recommended as a measure:

```
[
    ...
    'defaultRoute' => 'default/index',
    ...
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        ...
        'rules' => [
            ...
            '' => '',   // <- this line should be added
        ],
    ],
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is not the answer of question**, however it might be helpful to know:
there is a `catchAll` property in `yii\web\Application` which is defined as:

> The configuration specifying a controller action which should handle all user requests.

Usage:

```
'catchAll' => ['controller/action']
```

So, every request to  http://basic.com will call `controller/action`

Answer (score 1):

With yii2 I was able to do it in the urlmanager with:

```
'rules'=> [
        ['pattern'=>'<action>', 'route'=>'controller/<action>'],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the other solutions... If they do not work, then use my simple trick...

Just create an **index.php** page at the root.

Then, in that file, write this code:

```
return header('Location: http://your page location');
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'defaultRoute' don't work - check settings for 'urlManager'. Maybe default route is set there.

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [

            '' => 'site/index',  // this line should be chenged to ''=>''.

            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```